# Discrete Math Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

> Consider truth assignments involving only the propositional variables $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3$.
>
> Every such truth assignment gives a value of $1$ (representing true) or $0$ (representing false) to each variable. We can therefore think of a truth assignment $\tau$ as determining a four-bit integer $x_\tau$ depending on the values given to $x_0, x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$, and a four-bit integer $y_\tau$ depending on the values given to
>   $y_0, y_1, y_2$ and $y_3$.
>
> More precisely, with $\tau (x_i)$ being the truth value assigned to $x_i$, we can define the integers
>   $x_\tau = 2^3 \tau (x_3) + 2^2 \tau (x_2) + 2^1 \tau (x_1) + \tau (x_0)$ and $y_\tau = 2^3\tau (y_3) + 2^2 \tau (y_2) + 2^1 \tau (y_1) + \tau (y_0)$.
>
> Write a formula that is satisfied by exactly those truth assignments $\tau$ for which $x_\tau > y_\tau$ . Your formula may use any of the Boolean connectives introduced so far. Explain how you obtained your formula, and justify its correctness

Am I right in assuming that I would need to construct a formula for every single possibility where $x$ is the greater bit?

Comment: Do you mean $x\tau=2^3\tau(x_3)+2^2\tau(x_2)+2\tau(x_1)+\tau(x_0)$?

Comment: Also, what are the Boolean connectives you've been introduced to so far? And from the formulation of the question, you only need to come up with one formula.

Comment: Yes! Let me me change the format. We have done basics of predicate logic with two variables.

Comment: Quite trivially, you could set $\tau(x_i)=1$ and $\tau(y_i)=0$, i.e. all $x$'s are true and all $y$'s are false.

Comment: Could I? It sets both y and x as true in the question.

Comment: For instance:
$$x_0\land x_1\land x_2\land x_3\land (\neg y_0)\land (\neg y_1)\land (\neg y_2)\land (\neg y_3)$$
in which case: $x\tau=2^3+2^2+2^1+1=15$ and $y\tau=0$.

Comment: Alright, but how would that translate into a formula?

Comment: That's a formula, satisfied only if all $x$'s are true and $y$'s are false.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering more how would that look in Boolean connectives.

Comment: $\land$ is the Boolean connective AND, $\neg$ is the Boolean connective NOT. $a\land b$ is true if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are true. $\neg c$ is true if $c$ is false (it simply flips the truth value). Therefore, the formula I've given you is true if and only if every argument between the $\land$'s are true. That means that all $x$'s must be true, and all $\neg y$'s must be true, i.e. all $y$'s must be false.

Comment: If the high-order bits, x3 and y3,
are not equal, which of the two numbers is greater? If the two high-order bits are equal, how do we proceed
to determine which of the two numbers is greater?

Comment: First step is to make sure you understand, from the formula and explanations I've given you, why the only way to make the formula true is to have $x$'s true and $y$'s false. Then, you simply apply your function $\tau$ to each variable. $\tau$ will return $0$ if false, $1$ if true. Therefore, $\tau$ of any $x$, in this case, will return $1$. You can then compute your 4-bits integer, and you find $15$ (binary equivalent : 1111). Same thing for $y$'s: they're all false, so $\tau$ returns $0$ each time. Therefore, the corresponding integer is $0$ (0000). And of course, $15>0$.

Comment: Ohhhh, I understand now! Would you just explain why the formula you provided is the only one that can be true?

Comment: Oh no, it's not the only one that can be true. It's the most trivial one. You can create an infinite number of formulas that are true. But your exercise only ask to find one that is true, and satisfies $x\tau>y\tau$. Which is what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was under the impression that this question only had one possible formula and didn't come to think it could be done at such a simple level.

Comment: One more point. Formulas can be true under several different truth assignments. For instance, something like $a\lor b$, meaning "a OR b", is true if $a$ is true or if $b$ is true. In that case, there are three truth assignments that make it true: $a$ is true, $b$ is false; $a$ is false, $b$ is true; $a$ and $b$ are both true. My example has the advantage of being true ONLY in one configuration (due to the AND operator).

Comment: I wrote a proper answer, can you upvote it and accept it, so that we know that your question has been answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just re-writing my answer from the comments section.

$\tau$ is a function that assigns the binary value $0$ or $1$ to a propositional variable, depending on whether that variable has the truth assignment FALSE or TRUE (respectively).

We then compute the 4-bit integers $x_\tau$ and $y_\tau$ as follows:
\begin{cases}
x_\tau=2^3\tau(x_3)+2^2\tau(x_2)+2^1\tau(x_1)+2^0\tau(x_0)\\
y_\tau=2^3\tau(y_3)+2^2\tau(y_2)+2^1\tau(y_1)+2^0\tau(y_0)
\end{cases}
Therefore, the most trivial formula that satisfies $x_\tau>y_\tau$ will assign:
\begin{cases}
x_\tau=2^3\times 1+2^2\times 1+2^1\times 1+2^0\times 1=8+4+2+1=15=_{bin} 1111\\
y_\tau=2^3\times 0+2^2\times 0+2^1\times 0+2^0\times 0=0+0+0+0=0=_{bin} 0000\\
\end{cases}
In other words, we're looking for a logical formula that is true whenever the $x_i$ are true and the $y_i$ are false. Such a formula is given by:
$$x_0\land x_1\land x_2\land x_3\land (\neg y_0)\land (\neg y_1)\land (\neg y_2)\land (\neg y_3)$$
where we have used the two Boolean connectives $\land$ (AND) and $\neg$ (NOT). The AND connective yields TRUE if and only if both its arguments are TRUE. The NOT connective flips the truth-value of its argument, i.e. NOT TRUE=FALSE and NOT FALSE=TRUE.

Therefore, it can easily be seen that the formula above, where each element is connected by AND connectives, is true only when each element is TRUE. And in particular, the elements formed by NOT $y_i$ are true only when the $y_i$ are FALSE.